java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/uuid/Uuid when using JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer
I would like to use JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer to dynamically deserialize field of JSON. Deserialization is working great, but when I try to serialize object into JSON, following exception is thrown:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/uuid/Uuid

Below is minimal code to reproduce error. I guess there could be a problem in my pom.xml but I have no idea how to find where that mistake is.
fun main() {
    println(Json.encodeToString(Company("Company 1", "basic")))
}

object PlanSerializer2 : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<String>(String::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement) = String.serializer()
}

@Serializable
data class Company(
    val name: String,
    @Serializable(with = PlanSerializer2::class)
    val plan: String
)

My pom.xml
<properties>
    <ktor_version>2.3.12</ktor_version>
    <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
    <kotlin_version>2.0.10</kotlin_version>
    <logback_version>1.4.14</logback_version>
    <slf4j_version>2.0.9</slf4j_version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    <main.class>io.ktor.server.tomcat.EngineMain</main.class>
    <serialization.version>1.7.2</serialization.version>
</properties>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<repositories>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-ratelimiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-core-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-tomcat-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-client-apache-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-config-yaml-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-test-host-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-client-mock-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-debug</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlinx-serialization-json</artifactId>
        <version>${serialization.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-client-auth-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-client-content-negotiation-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-client-logging-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-double-receive-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
        <artifactId>ktor-server-servlet-jakarta-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${ktor_version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>kotlinx-serialization</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-serialization</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>**/*.yaml,**/*.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>21</source>
                <target>21</target>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Uuid is a recent addition to the standard library (2.0.20) that requires an opt in. Double check the version of Kotlin your runtime is using
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew2020.html#support-for-uuids-in-the-common-kotlin-standard-library

@DavidSoroko but the OP is not actually using UUID.

Uuid, not UUID. Most likely it is a transitive dependency of  kotlinx.serialization. It's latest version depends on 2.0.20

Thanks for replies. I dont use 2.0.20, only 2.0.10. Any idea how could I find dependency that is wrong?

Try downgrading serialization.version to 1.7.1. Ideally, there should be a flag to allow you to use 1.7.2 without Uuid, but I couldn't find one.

To add to the previous comment, the documentation of  kotlinx.serialization 1.7.2 explicitly mentions Kotlin 2.0.20:  https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/releases/tag/v1.7.2

The documentation says it "uses Kotlin 2.0.20 by default". What exactly does that mean? The word "default" by definition implies it only uses 2.0.20 if you don't tell it to use something else. But how?

You have:

kotlinx.serialization 1.7.2 which assumes Kotlin 2.0.20

Kotlin 2.0.10


As per comments, your options include:

Upgrading Kotlin to 2.0.20
Downgrading kotlinx.serialization to 1.7.1

